# Convert ARGB color string to int ARGB int format Color in android

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport, android-color, android-designer

I am required to pass ARGB color from 1 Activity to other activity as String. Now I am required to convert the same color string in other activity to be converted to int to pass into an argument in color method.

Here is my implementation:

**Activity1**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.java,Activity2.class);

...

i.putExtra("color1", "Color.argb(200, 69, 202, 252)");
i.putExtra("color2", "Color.argb(200, 48, 63, 159)");
startActivity(i);
```

Now, I am using this string in other class that's

**Activity2**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String color1 = i.getStringExtra("color1");
String color2 = i.getStringExtra("color2");

...

tvContent.setBackground(getGradientColor(Color.parseColor(color1), Color.parseColor(color1)));

...

public static GradientDrawable getGradientColor(int color1, int color2) {
    int[] colors = new int[2];
    colors[0] = color1;
    colors[1] = color2;

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, colors);

    gd.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);

    gd.setCornerRadius(50);
    gd.setStroke(0, Color.WHITE);

    return gd;
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.activity.SubListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
    at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:163)
    at com.gstechnovos.mathsploy.activity.SubListActivity.onCreate(SubListActivity.java:101)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing invalid `String` to [`Color.parseColor(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String)):

> Supported formats are: `#RRGGBB` or `#AARRGGBB`

I suggest operating on color ints from the beginning. Remove quotes from putExtras to just create argb int instead:

```
// Activity1
i.putExtra("color1", Color.argb(200, 69, 202, 252));
i.putExtra("color2", Color.argb(200, 48, 63, 159));
startActivity(i);
```

Then retrieve and use the integers in second activity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int color1 = i.getIntExtra("color1");
int color2 = i.getIntExtra("color2");

...

tvContent.setBackground(getGradientColor(color1, color2));

...
```